# mysql join tables limit specific table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I've created this SQL query in order to connect key variables and extract info from a database.

Firstly I used this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` a,`field_data_field_ypefthinos` b, `field_data_field_branch_chain` c, `field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia` d, `node_revision` e
WHERE a.uid = b.field_ypefthinos_uid
AND a.uid = 1
AND b.entity_id = c.entity_id
AND d.field_taxonomy_etairia_tid = c.field_branch_chain_tid
AND d.bundle = 'kouponia'
AND d.entity_id = e.nid
```

and then I converted it to this in order to be able to use stmt bind_result function

```
SELECT
users.uid, 
field_data_field_ypefthinos.field_ypefthinos_uid, 
field_data_field_ypefthinos.entity_id,
field_data_field_branch_chain.entity_id,
field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia.field_taxonomy_etairia_tid,
field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia.bundle,
field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia.entity_id,
node_revision.nid
FROM `users`,`field_data_field_ypefthinos`, `field_data_field_branch_chain`, `field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia`, `node_revision`
WHERE users.uid = field_data_field_ypefthinos.field_ypefthinos_uid
AND users.uid = 1
AND field_data_field_ypefthinos.entity_id = field_data_field_branch_chain.entity_id
AND field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia.field_taxonomy_etairia_tid = field_data_field_branch_chain.field_branch_chain_tid
AND field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia.bundle = 'kouponia'
AND field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia.entity_id = node_revision.nid
```

What I'd like to do next is to:

1) use table/fields aliases in order for the code to be easier maintained as I do in the first code.

2) Important: be able to limit the results from table field_data_field_ypefthinos to LIMIT 1.

My goal is to have a code like this:

```
SELECT a.uid, b.field_ypefthinos_uid, b.entity_id, c.entity_id, d.field_taxonomy_etairia_tid, c.field_branch_chain_tid, d.bundle, d.entity_id
FROM `users` a,`field_data_field_ypefthinos` b LIMIT 1, `field_data_field_branch_chain` c, `field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia` d, `node_revision` e
WHERE a.uid = b.field_ypefthinos_uid
AND a.uid = 1
AND b.entity_id = c.entity_id
AND d.field_taxonomy_etairia_tid = c.field_branch_chain_tid
AND d.bundle = 'kouponia'
AND d.entity_id = e.nid
```

Comment: You state that you want to limit the results to one record from table field_data_field_ypefthinos.  Before writing any code, you have to decide which record you want.

Comment: THe first record (match) that comes from field_data_field_ypefthinos, once a.uid = b.field_ypefthinos_uid has a match the script should continue

Comment: Is there a field that identifies the first record?  Lowest value in primary key field?  Earliest value of some date field?

Comment: That's what I am trying to achieve:

SELECT b.entity_id
FROM `users` a,`field_data_field_ypefthinos` b
WHERE a.uid = b.field_ypefthinos_uid
AND a.uid = 1
LIMIT 1 (OUTPUT: 626)

SELECT e.title
FROM `field_data_field_branch_chain` c, `field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia` d, `node_revision` e
AND c.entity_id = '626'
AND d.field_taxonomy_etairia_tid = c.field_branch_chain_tid
AND d.bundle = 'kouponia'
AND d.entity_id = e.nid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISTINCT did the job, the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.title
FROM `users` a,`field_data_field_ypefthinos` b, `field_data_field_branch_chain` c, `field_data_field_taxonomy_etairia` d, `node_revision` e
WHERE a.uid = b.field_ypefthinos_uid
AND a.uid = 1
AND b.entity_id = c.entity_id
AND d.field_taxonomy_etairia_tid = c.field_branch_chain_tid
AND d.bundle = 'kouponia'
AND d.entity_id = e.nid
```